# glTexImage2D splitting bytes across words in math-only shader in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

I am writing an array manipulation algorithm that is processed in the GPU instead of the CPU. I write a texture to an FBO, render it and then read the results. The problem I'm having is that the data going in doesn't match the data coming out. I am using RGBA to handle the 8-bit bytes as 4-byte words.

This app is for IOS on an iPhone and uses OpenGL ES 2.0.

The header file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <GLKit/GLKit.h>


@interface matmanip : UIViewController <GLKViewDelegate>
- (void) processmat;
@end
```

The program file:

```
#import "matmanip.h"
enum
{
    ATTRIB_VERTEX = 0,
    ATTRIB_UV,
    NUM_ATTRIBS
};

@interface matmanip (){
    GLuint          _texture;
    GLuint          _framebuffer;
    GLuint          _renderbuffer;
    GLint           _backingWidth;
    GLint           _backingHeight;
    GLfloat         _vertices[8];
    GLuint          _program;


}
@property (nonatomic,strong) EAGLContext *context;
@property (nonatomic,strong) GLKView *workingview;
@end

@implementation matmanip
    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
     return self;
}


- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
- (void) processmat   {
    unsigned int RGBAWidth;

    GLsizei XWidth = 20;
    GLsizei YHeight = 2;
    unsigned char* inputMatrix = malloc((YHeight*XWidth));

    for (int i = 0; i<XWidth*YHeight; i++) {
        inputMatrix[i] = 0;
    }
    inputMatrix[0]=37;

    RGBAWidth = (int)(XWidth/4); //4 bytes = 1 RGBA pixel


    if (!self.context) { // if not initialized
        self.context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
        if (!self.context || ![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context]) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to create ES context");
        }
        [self loadShaders];

        _workingview = [[GLKView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame context:self.context];

        CAEAGLLayer *eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer*) self.workingview.layer;
        eaglLayer.opaque = YES;
        eaglLayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:TRUE], kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking,
                                        kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat,
                                        nil];

        _workingview.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24;
        _workingview.drawableColorFormat = GLKViewDrawableColorFormatRGBA8888;
        _workingview.delegate = self;
        [self.view addSubview:self.workingview];
    }
    else {
        [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];
    }

    glUseProgram(_program);

    if (!(self.workingview.frame.size.width == RGBAWidth) || !(self.workingview.frame.size.height == YHeight)) {
        CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
        frame.size.height = YHeight;
        frame.size.width = RGBAWidth;
        self.workingview.frame = frame;
        self.view.frame = frame;


        glGenFramebuffers(1, &_framebuffer);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _framebuffer);

        glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_renderbuffer);
        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _renderbuffer);
        [_context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer*)self.workingview.layer];
        glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &_backingWidth);
        glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &_backingHeight);
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _renderbuffer);
        //        NSLog(@"%0x",glGetError());

        GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) ;
        if(status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
            NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", status);
        }

        _vertices[0] = -1.0f;  // x0
        _vertices[1] = -1.0f;  // y0
        _vertices[2] =  1.0f;  // ..
        _vertices[3] = -1.0f;
        _vertices[4] = -1.0f;
        _vertices[5] =  1.0f;
        _vertices[6] =  1.0f;  // x3
        _vertices[7] =  1.0f;  // y3



    }
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _renderbuffer);

    static const GLfloat texCoords[] = {
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f,
    };

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _framebuffer);
    glViewport(0, 0, _backingWidth, _backingHeight);

    glUseProgram(_program);

    if (!validateProgram(_program))
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to validate program");
        return;
    }

    if (!_texture) {
        glGenTextures(1, &_texture);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _texture);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
         NSLog(@"%0x",glGetError());

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, RGBAWidth, YHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
        NSLog(@"%0x",glGetError());
    }

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _texture);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(_program, "t_texture"), 0);

    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0,
                    RGBAWidth,
                    YHeight,
                    GL_RGBA,
                    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                    inputMatrix);



    NSLog(@"inputMatrix[0] %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x",inputMatrix[0],inputMatrix[1],inputMatrix[2],inputMatrix[3],inputMatrix[4],inputMatrix[5],inputMatrix[6],inputMatrix[7],inputMatrix[8],inputMatrix[9],inputMatrix[10],inputMatrix[11],inputMatrix[12],inputMatrix[13],inputMatrix[14],inputMatrix[15],inputMatrix[16],inputMatrix[17],inputMatrix[18],inputMatrix[19]);
    NSLog(@"inputMatrix[1] %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x",inputMatrix[20],inputMatrix[21],inputMatrix[22],inputMatrix[23],inputMatrix[24],inputMatrix[25],inputMatrix[26],inputMatrix[27],inputMatrix[28],inputMatrix[29],inputMatrix[30],inputMatrix[31],inputMatrix[32],inputMatrix[33],inputMatrix[34],inputMatrix[35],inputMatrix[36],inputMatrix[37],inputMatrix[38],inputMatrix[39]);





    //draw RECT
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, _vertices);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);

    //ATTRIB_TEXTUREPOSITON
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_UV, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, texCoords);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_UV);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _framebuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _renderbuffer);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _renderbuffer);

    glColorMask(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE);

    glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);  // just a random color
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    [self.context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
    GLubyte* outputMatrix = (GLubyte*) malloc(_backingWidth*_backingHeight*sizeof(GLubyte)*4);


    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

    glReadPixels(0, 0, RGBAWidth, YHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, outputMatrix);

    NSLog(@"outputMatrix[0] %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x",outputMatrix[0],outputMatrix[1],outputMatrix[2],outputMatrix[3],outputMatrix[4],outputMatrix[5],outputMatrix[6],outputMatrix[7],outputMatrix[8],outputMatrix[9],outputMatrix[10],outputMatrix[11],outputMatrix[12],outputMatrix[13],outputMatrix[14],outputMatrix[15],outputMatrix[16],outputMatrix[17],outputMatrix[18],outputMatrix[19]);
    NSLog(@"outputMatrix[1] %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x %0x",outputMatrix[20],outputMatrix[21],outputMatrix[22],outputMatrix[23],outputMatrix[24],outputMatrix[25],outputMatrix[26],outputMatrix[27],outputMatrix[28],outputMatrix[29],outputMatrix[30],outputMatrix[31],outputMatrix[32],outputMatrix[33],outputMatrix[34],outputMatrix[35],outputMatrix[36],outputMatrix[37],outputMatrix[38],outputMatrix[39]);
    NSLog(@"%0x",glGetError());

    free(inputMatrix);
    free(outputMatrix);

}


- (BOOL)loadShaders
{
    GLuint vertShader, fragShader;
    NSString *vertShaderPathname, *fragShaderPathname;

    // Create shader program.
    _program = glCreateProgram();

    // Create and compile vertex shader.
    vertShaderPathname = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"matrixmod" ofType:@"vs"];
    if (![self compileShader:&vertShader type:GL_VERTEX_SHADER file:vertShaderPathname]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to compile vertex shader");
        return NO;
    }

    // Create and compile fragment shader.
    fragShaderPathname = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"matrixmod" ofType:@"fs"];
    if (![self compileShader:&fragShader type:GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER file:fragShaderPathname]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to compile fragment shader");
        return NO;
    }

    // Attach vertex shader to program.
    glAttachShader(_program, vertShader);

    // Attach fragment shader to program.
    glAttachShader(_program, fragShader);

    // Bind attribute locations.
    // This needs to be done prior to linking.
    glBindAttribLocation(_program, ATTRIB_VERTEX, "position");
    glBindAttribLocation(_program, ATTRIB_UV, "xy");

    // Link program.
    if (![self linkProgram:_program]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to link program: %d", _program);

        if (vertShader) {
            glDeleteShader(vertShader);
            vertShader = 0;
        }
        if (fragShader) {
            glDeleteShader(fragShader);
            fragShader = 0;
        }
        if (_program) {
            glDeleteProgram(_program);
            _program = 0;
        }

        return NO;
    }

    // Release vertex and fragment shaders.

    if (vertShader) {
        glDetachShader(_program, vertShader);
        glDeleteShader(vertShader);
    }
    if (fragShader) {
        glDetachShader(_program, fragShader);
        glDeleteShader(fragShader);
    }
    //    NSLog(@"%0x",glGetError());

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)compileShader:(GLuint *)shader type:(GLenum)type file:(NSString *)file
{
    GLint status;
    const GLchar *source;

    source = (GLchar *)[[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:file encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil] UTF8String];
    if (!source) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to load vertex shader");
        return NO;
    }

    *shader = glCreateShader(type);
    glShaderSource(*shader, 1, &source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(*shader);

#if defined(DEBUG)
    GLint logLength;
    glGetShaderiv(*shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength);
    if (logLength > 0) {
        GLchar *log = (GLchar *)malloc(logLength);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(*shader, logLength, &logLength, log);
        NSLog(@"Shader compile log:\n%s", log);
        free(log);
    }
#endif

    glGetShaderiv(*shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
    if (status == 0) {
        glDeleteShader(*shader);
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)linkProgram:(GLuint)prog
{
    GLint status;
    glLinkProgram(prog);

#if defined(DEBUG)
    GLint logLength;
    glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength);
    if (logLength > 0) {
        GLchar *log = (GLchar *)malloc(logLength);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(prog, logLength, &logLength, log);
        NSLog(@"Program link log:\n%s", log);
        free(log);
    }
#endif

    glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
    if (status == 0) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}





static BOOL validateProgram(GLuint prog)
{
    GLint status;

    glValidateProgram(prog);

    GLint logLength;
    glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength);
    //    NSLog(@"Framebuffer status = %d, %d",glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER),GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE);
    if (logLength > 0)
    {
        GLchar *log = (GLchar *)malloc(logLength);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(prog, logLength, &logLength, log);
        NSLog(@"Program validate log:\n%s", log);
    }

    glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, &status);
    if (status == GL_FALSE) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to validate program %d", prog);
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}


@end
```

The vertex shader is:

```
attribute vec2 position;
attribute vec2 xy;
varying vec2 xyVarying;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
    xyVarying = xy;
}
```

For testing purposes, the fragment shader just loads the 32-bit word at the corresponding texel - a simple pass through. I should get the same matrix out, just upside-down.
The fragment shader is:

```
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D t_texture;
varying highp vec2 xyVarying;
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(t_texture, xyVarying);

}
```

My result is - strange.

Notice that I set the entire matrix to zero except for the first byte which is 37 (25H) in this example.

```
inputMatrix[0] 25 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
inputMatrix[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
outputMatrix[0] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
outputMatrix[1] 9 0 0 0 7 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The problem is that the 25H has been spread out into 9H, 7H and 2H. I get similar results for any number and if I put a value in the 2nd octet, I get similar results in the 2nd octets of the first three bytes. What have I done wrong? I presume I'm accidentally converting from RGBA to byte or something similar.

Updated:

Thanks to Reto Koradi's suggestion, I changed the min and mag filters from

```
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

to

```
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

and got much closer results. Then I realized I wasn't using a power of 2 for the width, so I changed the matrix from [20,2] to [16,4] and fed in the ascii table from ? to ~ (63-126).

The x and y coordinates appear to be doubled / halved.

```
inputMatrix[0] 3f 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4a 4b 4c 4d 4e
inputMatrix[1] 4f 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 5a 5b 5c 5d 5e
inputMatrix[2] 5f 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6a 6b 6c 6d 6e
inputMatrix[3] 6f 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7a 7b 7c 7d 7e

outputMatrix[0] 6f 70 71 72 6f 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 73 74 75 76
outputMatrix[1] 6f 70 71 72 6f 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 73 74 75 76
outputMatrix[2] 5f 60 61 62 5f 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 63 64 65 66
outputMatrix[3] 5f 60 61 62 5f 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 63 64 65 66
```

The corner four 32-bit words are stretched across the matrix (upside down, but I expected that).

Comment: I don't think you can really do this (storing bytes in shader floats). There is no guarantee of an exact amount of precision. The floats might be getting rounded at some stage.

Comment: By using 1:1 mapping of pixels to matrix dimensions and highp floats, it shouldn't matter unless the matrixes get REALLY large. The precision errors should stay small enough that the nearest pixel is the correct one.

Comment: Most devices round highp down to mediump (they don't support highp). Any loss of precision whatsoever I would think would completely mess up your bytes.

Comment: Nevermind, I see you're sticking with iOS. If doing this on Android, there's no guarantee of highp.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're seeing the result of linear interpolation, based on the way you specified your texture parameters:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

If you want to read the value of a single texel, instead of interpolating between multiple texels, change this to:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

Comment: Hmm. That made a difference, but it's rounding.

Comment: inputMatrix[0] 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4a 4b 4c 4d 4e 4f 50 51 52 53 54

Comment: inputMatrix[1] 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6a 6b 6c 6d 6e 6f 70 71 72 73 74

Comment: outputMatrix[0] 61 62 63 64 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 65 66 67 68 69 6a 6b 6c

Comment: outputMatrix[1] 61 62 63 64 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 65 66 67 68 69 6a 6b 6c

Comment: It seems to have grabbed adjacent pixels. The 61,62,63,64 is propagated to four pixels. Or maybe it's doubling?

Comment: Perhaps I need to round or trunc the x,y inside the fragment shader?

Comment: Actually, that looks suspiciously like the shader is trying to stretch the texture array to fit a larger space.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. The GLKview was a retina display and the line

```
glViewport(0, 0, _backingWidth, _backingHeight);
```

was doubling the canvas size in both the s and t directions because _backingWidth and _backingHeight were the pixel counts (retina pixel counts) of the GLKView. Because I resize my GLKView to whatever I want (and never display it), I can use the actual width and height.

```
glViewport(0, 0, RGBAWidth, YHeight);
```

That fixed it.

```
inputMatrix[0] 3f 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4a 4b 4c 4d 4e
inputMatrix[1] 4f 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 5a 5b 5c 5d 5e
inputMatrix[2] 5f 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6a 6b 6c 6d 6e
inputMatrix[3] 6f 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7a 7b 7c 7d 7e

outputMatrix[0] 6f 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7a 7b 7c 7d 7e
outputMatrix[1] 5f 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6a 6b 6c 6d 6e
outputMatrix[2] 4f 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 5a 5b 5c 5d 5e
outputMatrix[3] 3f 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4a 4b 4c 4d 4e
```

Thanks for the help Reto!